# How to merge 2 tables together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 a table with this structure:

[Database1].[dbo].[Users_Detail]

```
UserID    NickName    
-------------------------------
1         book1       
2         book2       
3         book2       
4         tv1
```

[Database2].[dbo].[Users_Detail]

```
UserID    NickName    
-------------------------------
1         nick1       
2         nick2       
3         book2       
4         tv2
5         tv3  
6         tv1
```

I have 2 tables with this structure where the UserID column is linked to the Users_Detail

[Database1].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost]

```
ID      UserID       Value    
-------------------------------
1         3         Value1       
2         3         Value2       
3         3         Value3       
4         4         Value4
```

[Database2].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost]

```
ID        UserID    NickName    
-------------------------------
1          3         Value12       
2          2         Value13       
3          4         Value14       
4          4         Value15
5          6         Value16  
6          6         Value16
```

I want to convert this table to:

[Database1].[dbo].[Users_Detail]

```
UserID    NickName    
-------------------------------
1         book1       
2         book2       
3         book2       
4         tv1    
5         tv3    
6         nick1       
7         nick2       
8         book2       
9         tv2
10         tv1
```

[Database1].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost]

```
ID      UserID       Value    
-------------------------------
1         3         Value1       
2         3         Value2       
3         3         Value3       
4         4         Value4 
5         8         Value12       
6         7         Value13       
7         9         Value14       
8         9         Value15
9         10        Value16  
10        10        Value16
```

I want the duplicate userid columns to be able to change to another userid without duplicates and add.

I have a Sys_User_Ghost table with a userid column associated with the userid at Users_Detail. I want it to sync with the duplicate userids changed in the question above.

Comment: Have you looked at `UNION (ALL)`?

Comment: I want to merge data. Add data from Database2 to Database1.

Comment: Then use an `INSERT` statement...?

Comment: It will give an error if there is a duplicate userid

Comment: I want the duplicate userid columns to be able to change to another userid without duplicates and add

Comment: And why do you not explain *any of that* in the question? You don't even show us your attempt not the error above.

Comment: It was my mistake to post this for not making the question clear. sorry

Answer (score 1):

For `User_Details` table use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO [Database1].[dbo].[Users_Detail] (UserID, NickName) 
    SELECT UserID, NickName 
    FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Users_Detail]
```

For `Sys_User_Ghost` table use this query:

```
INSERT INTO [Database1].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost] (ID, UserID, Value)  
    SELECT ID, UserID, Value 
    FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost]
```

Using these queries from database2 tables data insert into database1 tables, you can check using following query

```
SELECT * FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Users_Detail]

SELECT * FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in below approach,

For Users_Detail Table,

```
select * from [Database1].[dbo].[Users_Detail]
union all
select * from [Database2].[dbo].[Users_Detail]
```

For Sys_User_Ghost table,

```
select * from [Database1].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost]
union all
select * from [Database2].[dbo].[Sys_User_Ghost]
```

Note that if you dont want to take duplicates then use union instead of unionall.

See here details about sql union and union all .

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-union-vs-union-all-in-sql-server/

Comment: I want to merge data. Add data from Database2 to Database1.

Comment: then you can do like 

Insert Into [Database1].[dbo].[Users_Detail] (UserID,NickName) Select 
UserID,NickName from [Database2].[dbo].[Users_Detail]

Comment: The duplicate key value (Userid).  I want the key value to be automatically converted to another value without duplicates

Comment: Please see the full information above

Comment: Columns with no duplicate userid will be added. Columns with duplicate usage codes will be converted to a different number